# Get file as AJAX's response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have a generic Ajax call routine that I use to call a function in node.js.   This function reads a file from the server(xls mostly) then streams it back to client.

Here is my implementation in Node.js (server-side):

```
    // FILE DOESNT EXISTS BEFORE, 
    // FILE IS CREATED HERE THEN SAVED IN SERVER AS A FILE
    fs.readFile("/path/to/file.xlsx", function(err, file){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=file.xlsx');
        res.write(file, 'binary');
        res.end();
    });
```

And this is my ajax call that I use.

```
$('#submit').click(function()
{
   $.ajax({
    url: '/',
    type:'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });      
})
```

I successfully get binary data printed in my console (`console.log(data)`). My question is how to convert this `data` to a file  with proper extension and then prompt the browser to save them ?

Any suggestion or another workaround ?

Comment: Maybe just use `window.location.href = "your url";` and let the browser do all that?

Comment: No way, since this file is created during the request, it doesn't exists before.

Comment: That doesn't actually matter.  Your node.js returns the contents of a file.  You can either let the browser handle the file-saving business or (as in the answer below), you can go to the trouble of doing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. It works but, since I have to implement this in much larger system with angular (MVC model) I just can't do that. All request must go through model. That's why I explicitly write ajax's function there, I expect a solution that I can implement in angular. But yours works in jQuery implementation nevertheless

Answer (score 3):

Try using `FileReader` , `Blob` , `a` element , `download` attribute

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
   $.ajax({
    url: '/',
    type:'POST',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          $("a").attr({"href": e.target.result, "download":"filename"})
          .get().click()
        } 
        reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([data]));
    });      
})
```

Comment: still trying to implement this. I've never used Blob before, I'll look forward to it. I have a problem with $("a") though, what is it ?

Comment: @denny `$("a")` was used as an example of existing `<a>` element in `document` . Try adding an `<a>` element to `document` having a unique `className` or `id` , substituting `$("a.unique")` or `$("a#unique")` for `$("a")` followed by `.attr({"href": e.target.result, "download":"filename"})
          .get().click()`

Comment: I get error: 'click' function undefined. Do I need to add <a> in HTML?

Comment: _"Do I need to add <a> in HTML?"_ Yes

Comment: are you sure that FIleReader is compatible with node's binary data type ? Like Excel XLSX above ? I did what you said. File successfully downloaded, but my office can't open it and says it's corrupted although the file is perfectly fine.

Comment: $("a#link").attr({"href": e.target.result, "download":"file.xlsx"}).get().click()

Comment: @denny Try substituting `XMLHttpRequest` for jQuery `$.ajax()` , `URL.createObjectURL` for `FileReader` 



plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/T85SEN6G8urZq6WsGumy?p=info